# jquery - Draggable image when image is larger than the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Making an image draggable does some pretty wacky things when the image is larger than the container... Does anyone know a way around this?

Here's my code...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("img").draggable({ containment: "div", scroll: false });

    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    div {
        width:500px; 
        height:423px; 
        position:relative; 
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

and...

```
<div>
    <img src="images/map.jpg" width="1000" height="845" alt="Map" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working if you set the the bounds manually:

```
$("img").draggable({ containment: [0, 0, 500, 423], scroll: false });
```

Comment: Almost there! You need to set negative bounds... this works:
$("img").draggable({ containment: [-500, -422, 0, 0], scroll: false });

Comment: You, @Tom, saved my life. Thank you, good sir! I would have never guessed.

Answer (score 2):

I chose to set the containment dynamically based off the parent and child  size by doing the following, JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lesuto/0wm7wfy4/4/):

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id='dragx']").draggable({
    drag : function(event,ui){
      var parent = ui.helper[0].parentNode;

      var dragWidth = ui.helper[0].clientWidth;
      var parentWidth = parent.clientWidth;
      var dragHeight = ui.helper[0].clientHeight;
      var parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;

      var widthDifference = dragWidth - parentWidth;
      var heightDifference = dragHeight - parentHeight;

      if(ui.position.left > 0) ui.position.left = 0;
      else if(ui.position.left < -widthDifference) ui.position.left = -widthDifference;

      if(ui.position.top > 0) ui.position.top = 0;
      else if(ui.position.top < -heightDifference) ui.position.top = -heightDifference;

      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you're using draggable properly. The point of it is to pick up the image and put it somewhere. If the image is larger than the container, how can you know where you're putting it? It's not the same as if you want to grab the image and make the container scroll as you drag.

Now, that said, I think it's a bug (or maybe a feature?) that makes the outer edges snap to the container edges if the inner element is larger.

Are you trying to scroll the map while the mouse is clicked and dragged?