# JQuery light box Draggable Image inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to perform something
Which is viewing Big images inside something like a lighbox but high resolution let's say 1200x1600 or bigger, What I have in mind is to view a Lightbox with absolute Width and height like 800x600, and the Image will be draggable/Moveable inside the box
I think it's possible, But is there any ready Jquery plugin for such thing?
or Can you give me a tip for how to make it draggable inside a Div if I will make my own custom lightbox.

Comment: why not check JQZOOM at http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Comment: thanks, it's pretty similar to what I want, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small script will do this. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4016004/630321). I created a tiny [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtmdY/) to try this out and it works perfectly. It can be easily included inside your custom lightbox. Below is the original code with slight modification

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("img").draggable({ containment: [-500, -422, 0, 0], scroll: false });

    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    div {
        width:500px; 
        height:423px; 
        position:relative; 
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

The HTML is:

```
<div>
        <img src="http://megapack.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/High-Resolution-Wallpapers-2.jpg" width="1000" height="845" alt="Map" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try JQ Zoom, as i mentioned in comments http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Also you can check more plugins if JQZoom dont fit your needs

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-image-zoom.html